# flutter Xcode error Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

After I integrated the flutter project into the iOS project, I have to 'clean' it with Xcode every time I run the iOS project, otherwise it will report an error. Error content:
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Comment: Your question is not understandable. Kindly ask it in an appropriate way.

Comment: Please mention Xcode version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you have to apply or set a minimum deployment target in Xcode or in your project. Xcode will show you a recommended update while building the project just click on it and apply to perform changes and it will automatically change in necessary files